# Nginx + Passenger, getting truncated responses

Tags: nginx, phusion-passenger, redmine

Getting truncated responses for big attachments in Redmine, served by Nginx + Passenger.

Error log says like following:

```
[ pid=11234 thr=3070954384 file=ext/nginx/HelperAgent.cpp:568 time=2010-11-23 16:05:29.414 ]: Couldn't forward the HTTP response back to the HTTP client: It seems the user clicked on the 'Stop' button in his browser.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We had this issue on our staging machine and it was related to a permission issue in nginx' proxy_temp-folder( /opt/nginx/proxy_temp in our case)

Removing the folder and restarting nginx fixed the problem.

Comment: You can find out this directory by looking if it is defined in your config somewhere (proxy_temp_path), if not, run nginx -V. Either proxy_temp is defined, and if not, it is <prefix>/proxy_temp

Answer (score 1):

Problem could be solved by using Standalone Passenger instead of Nginx module in my case.

However this is quite interesting, as Standalone Passenger is based on Nginx. Maybe it just uses more proper config.

Answer (score 0):

We are running nginx 1.0.3 on ubuntu 12.04 and had the same problem. What we did was replacing the deprecated `rails_spawn_method smart` with `passenger_spawn_method smart` in nginx.conf. The problem disappeared since.